# ACL permissions on Chroot directory

Tags: linux, access-control-list, chroot

I have the Named service in a Chroot environment, I need a user to be able to modify the live files of the path `/var/named/chroot/etc` and I do not want to give full permissions with `sudo`, I have used the ACL lists to grant that user so that can modify the content, with the following order.

```
setfacl -R -m d:u:myuser:rwx /var/named/chroot/etc
```

I have applied inheritance so that future files and directories created by that user can be managed, but I get a permission denied when trying to create a file with the specified user.

```
$ touch testfile
touch: cannot touch ‘testfile’: Permission denied
```

The ACL tables were applied correctly.

```
# file: etc/
# owner: root
# group: named
user::rwx

group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:myuser:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

I don't understand why I can't write, do I have to apply those permissions to the root of the var? That is to say in /var/named ?

Thanks.